# Flask-Socketio emits only for first message

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, sqlalchemy, mqtt

Using Flask-Socketio and Flask-Mqtt:

```
@mqtt.on_message()
def handle_mqtt_message(client, userdata, message):

    ### Extract from Payload ###
    payload_list = message.payload.decode().split()
    time_list = [int(x) for x in re.split(r'[-T:.]', payload_list[2])]
    tstmpObj = datetime(time_list[0], #Year
                        time_list[1], #Month
                        time_list[2], #Day
                        time_list[3], #Hour
                        time_list[4], #Minute
                        time_list[5]  #Sec
                        )

    ### make dict from payload data ###
    data = dict(mssid = random.randint(0,10000),
                fduid = "FDU-"+message.topic[-6:],
                evnty = payload_list[0],
                tstmp = tstmpObj.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y - %I:%M:%S %p"),
                locur = payload_list[1])

    ### Print dictionary ###
    print(data)

    ### Real-Time Alert on webpage ###
    socketio.emit('mqtt_message', data=data)

    ### Insert message into database ###
    with create_app().app_context():
        event = Evntlg(fduid = data['fduid'],
                        evnty = data['evnty'],
                        tstmp = tstmpObj,
                        locur = data['locur'])
        db.session.add(event)
        db.session.commit()
```

Socketio.emit() works only on First onMessage() and not after that.
I'm using application factory and also blueprints.
All received messages are still inserted into the database properly.

##EDIT##
Code related to monkey-patching - patching since before the app runs.

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()

from floodwatch import create_app, socketio

app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, host='localhost', port=5000, debug=True)
```

I have to CTRL-C in the terminal and start it again to get RT messages again - but that too only for the first time and never again for the same session.

Comment: Are you using eventlet or gevent servers? If yes, have you monkey patched the standard library?

Comment: Yes, I am monkey patching with Eventlet as early as possible in the application. In fact, the first line of code executed is monkey patching. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Miguel is it because during database insertion the current app switches to the app that we created in the `with` statement? Maybe that's why socket doesn't work... because the new app is not running through socketio (0_0) Am I right here?